# How to render in Angular if the server is Spring?

Tags: angular, spring

Well that, what the title says, if I have a server that is in Spring and I want to pre-teach angular, how do I do it?, With universal angular it would take away the dynamism and it would have to pre-train a lot of components and it would take away the grace of the client-server architecture.

Comment: could you please rephrase? You are using the word apprentice wrong. If you are asking how to code in Angular while the backend is in Spring then there are books/tutorials just on that - to big of a topic to be answered here

Answer (score 0):

you can start here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

In general Frond End (Angular) and Back end (Spring) shouldn't know anything about each other and therefore you can and should learn them separately. Learn Spring Boot well, using only Thymeleaf and Bootstrap and when you have learned that feel free to learn JS and then Angular to make yourself a full stack developer.